# Twitter Bootstrap CSS: columns not filling div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand the `container > row > col-size-#` css format for creating responsive columns.  There is an area of our site where we need to use defined column widths inside a container and do not use the `container > row > col-size-#` format.

```
.special-area{
  width: 300px;
}

.special-area .one-third{
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The expected outcome is 3 columns each 100px wide displayed side by side in 1 row.
Instead, we are getting 2 columns side by side and the 3rd column underneath the 1st.

How can we make 3 columns side by side?

Comment: Use your web inspector and find out what width is actually getting assigned to the columns. Then check the width of the container. If the  container isn't wide enough, it will force the third column into the second row.

Comment: Can you post your HTML or create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `display:inline-block`, that means those divs are acting like words. And you know, for word, a space is counted. You can use following to collapse spaces.

```
.special-area{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.special-area .one-third{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: That gets them on the same line, but the spaces are still present, and the third div extends past the 300px mark.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/w4467/4/) demonstrates.  I managed to use this approach and make it fit by adding `letter-spacing:-5px` to the `special-area` class.

Comment: Understood. Then you can use `font-size:0;` solution.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  That seems preferable to the negative `letter-spacing`.  Good solution!

Comment: I added the `font-size:0;` to `.special-area` and this works great.  Thanks.

Comment: There are some problems with this approach too though as each child requires a font-size declaration.  See me answer below for all the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Float the inner `DIV`s and they'll be on the same line, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/w4467/).

**The HTML**

```
<div class="special-area">
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.special-area{
  width: 300px;
}

.special-area .one-third{
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:red;
  height:1px;
  float:left;
}
```

Height and background color added to demonstrate.

Comment: This answer definitely works but for many other reasons I did not want to float the divs.  For others reading this, floats will work but may cause other issues so be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier deftly explains why this happens and presents multiple solutions at `http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/`

The solutions by @Iqbal and @MatthewJohnson work.  Another option that doesn't require css is to type the html differently:

```
<div class="special-area">
  <div class="one-third">
    Content</div><div class="one-third">
    Content</div><div class="one-third">
    Content</div>
</div>
```