# Minify / Compress / Remove Whitespace in HTML in an automated manner

Tags: html, ruby, capistrano, whitespace

Trying to remove whitespace within HTML files including both non-necessary whitespace normally used for easy to read code and whitespace between html elements which [cause styling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992269/twitter-bootstrap-css-columns-not-filling-div).

Requirements
 1. remove whitespace in html including trivial formatting whitespace
    and whitespace between html tags.
 2. can be used automatically via scripts (preferably able to be tied
    into Capistrano tasks).
 3. Source code retains normal formatting (readability) in repo.

How can we accomplish these tasks in an automated fashion?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the same thing in `php` using the below method:

```
ob_start(function($buffer){$buffer = preg_replace(array('/ {2,}/','/<!--.*?-->|\t|(?:\r?\n[ \t]*)+/s'),array(' ',''),$buffer);return $buffer;});
```